# how to set system ip programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ip-address, uac

C++

how to programmatically change system IP...

and if the the account has Limited Rights how to use the password to perform the task

Comment: System's don't have IPs, interfaces have IPs (your network card for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366302(v=VS.85).aspx) on msdn.  I believe the function you should look into is:

```
DWORD AddIPAddress(
  __in   IPAddr Address,
  __in   IPMask IpMask,
  __in   DWORD IfIndex,
  __out  PULONG NTEContext,
  __out  PULONG NTEInstance
);
```